# Howto add fade in / fade out to this thumb preview

Tags: javascript, fadein, onmouseover, setattribute, fadeout

How can I add some fade-in on hovering the thumbs?

http://jsfiddle.net/GAa7D/1/

The magic js which needs fade:

```
function showT( image ){document.getElementById( 'ima' ).setAttribute('src',image )}
```

some more:

```
<img id="ima" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" height="75" width="75"/>

<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/cossington_smith-12-hp.jpg' )">pic 1</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/earthday12-hp.jpg' )">pic 2</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/Friedrich_Frobel-2012-hp.jpg' )">pic 3</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick jQuery example:

```
$('#ima').fadeOut(function(){
    $('#ima').attr('src', image).fadeIn()
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAa7D/2/)

To make it fade in/out faster:

```
$('#ima').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#ima').attr('src', image).fadeIn('fast')
});
```

You could also swap out `'fast'` with the fade duration in milliseconds.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAa7D/3/)

Comment: THANX, I like this one best :)

Comment: on second looks: is there any way to make it go faster?
or just only fade in?

Comment: Thanks, I had a border round the img which made it look bad, but a div with border did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

`$("#thumbnail-1").hover(function() {$(this).fadeIn(fast);},function() {$(this).fadeOut(fast);});`

CSS3:

```
a {
opacity:0.3;
transition:opacity 1s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 1s; /* Safari */
}

a:hover {
opacity:1;
}
```